# Anaconda - updating packages in a specific virtual environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I have Python 3.x installed as my root Anaconda environment. I also have the Intel Distribution for Python installed as a virtual environment. When I do `conda update --all`, in either environment it only looks for the main Conda packages to update. If I instead first set `conda config --add channels intel`, it'll search for the Intel-related packages when I update packages in either environment. However, I only want it to update the Intel packages in the Intel environment whereas I don't want it to update to the Intel variants in my root environment.

How can I update all my packages in a given environment in this way?

Comment: For update all packages in a conda virtual environment
you can try this:
`conda update -n myenv --all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force conda to only look in the appropriate channel when updating.

```
# In the root env
conda update -c defaults --override-channels --all
# In the Intel env
conda update -c intel --override-channels --all
```

Comment: If you ```update --all``` the ```root``` or ```base``` env, shall the other environments be updated as well?